# Minimizing $\det(D)$ for all diagonal matrices $D$ that satisfy $D+B \succeq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix and let $B$ be the block bipartite matrix

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&A \\
 A^{T}&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I came across the following optimization problem, which can be cast as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & x_{1}\ldots{x_{2n}} &\\
\text{subject to}&  B+ D \succeq 0 \\
                 &                                                x_{j} \geq 0, &j=1 ,\dots, 2n
\end{array}
\end{equation*} over the regime of diagonal matrices $D$ with non-negative entries $x_{j}$ along the diagonal.

I want to see if there was a clever way to recast the problem above as a convex linear program that can be solved in polynomial time.

Initially, I thought about rephrasing the constraint $B+D \succeq 0$ as $I+ D^{-1/2}BD^{-1/2}$ and minimizing $-2\log(x_{1} \ldots {x_{2n}})$ but I don't think this region $I+ D^{-1/2}BD^{-1/2}$ is convex (at least I'm getting errors in software).

Another idea, was to recast $B+D \succeq 0$ as the Schur complement $D_{1} - A^{T}D_{2}^{-1}A \succeq 0$ where $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ are the top left and bottom right blocks of $D$ which could allow me to rephrase the objective in terms of $D_{2}^{-1}$ which may allow me to optimize first over $D_{2}$ and then using the other Schur complement optimize over $D_{1}$.

Also, if this problem has come up in other contexts, I'd love to know.

Comment: It is unclear in what non-tautological way you want the solution to be expressed.

Comment: Sorry, I guess vaguely I’m looking for any convex optimization problem whose solution corresponds to a solution to the optimization problem mentioned in the post. I’m not sure if that helps.

Comment: For example,  $B= M^{T} M \succeq 0$ then minimizing the determinant over all diagonals $D$ such that $D-B \succeq 0$ corresponds to minimizing $-\log(det(D^{-1})$ over the region were the Schur complement $I - MD^{-1}M^T \succeq 0$. For the problem here, $B$ is not positive definite though

Comment: What happens for $n=1$?

Comment: I think for $n=1$, one may not need such a program to find the optimum $D$. I think in this case, we have $B$  is a scalar multiple of $[[0,1],[1,0]]$, I think in this case  $D = diag([1,1])$. The case when $n=2$ is harder.

Comment: A direct way is to use Sylvester conditions on the positivity of the principle minors of $B+D$. So this seeks the minimum of $f(x_1,\ldots,x_{2n})=\prod_{i=1}^{2n}x_i$ under those (affine) conditions-constraints of the minors. For example if $A$ is a generalised real permutation with non zero entries $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, then $\min[f(x_1,\ldots,x_{2n})]=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^2$.